# Chrome debugger, horizontal scrollbar blocking variable values on hover

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This has been happening for a few weeks now. Can't find anything on the net, anyone have any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

**Screenshot**
[image: Chrome debugger mouse hover]

Note: I'm hovering over a variable containing a string.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you using the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: @Gothdo Yep. (50.0.2661.102) Auto updates enabled and everything.

Comment: It's a zooming [issue](http://superuser.com/a/1053794). Try to zoom in and out with ctrl +/- or ctrl mouse wheel within the developer Tools window.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The real fix here is to zoom in/out in the console window, or reset the zoom with Ctrl + 0

Comment: I had the same issue with default font size (Ctrl 0). Increasing the font by one level (Ctrl +) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, that's a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599214)! You can *star* the issue (hollowed out star icon on the left-hand side by the issue number heading) to show it is affecting you as well.

Looks like it might be due to an altered default browser font size... I'll do some digging here this evening and see if I can come up with anything to help triage this further.

Answer (score 2):

For me switching the debug tools to dark theme fixed the issue, resetting the zoom had no effect:
Settings -> Preferences -> Appearance, then choose theme Dark

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me too. Actually, it seems that after switching to dark theme, if you switch back to light theme, the issue won't appear anymore.