# Chrome dev tools, cannot hover over value in sources panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I cannot view a value when I hover over it, the overlay is too small to see the value, can anyone tell me how I can view these values?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216999/chrome-debugger-horizontal-scrollbar-blocking-variable-values-on-hover